# how to return a column in the query based on the date in another table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I try describe in detail.
That's the first table

```
itogo=structure(list(cfo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "НСК", class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("PlanНСК1", "PlanНСК2", 
"PlanНСК3", "PlanНСК4", "PlanНСК5"), class = "factor"), customer_name = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ТС", class = "factor"), 
    sales_volume_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "от 50 до 100 кг", class = "factor"), 
    shop_group_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "loc", class = "factor"), product_id = c(11628L, 
    11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 
    11709L), shop_code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "02293НСК", class = "factor"), 
    rpost2019.01 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    rpost2019.02 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    rpost2019.03 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    rpost2019.04 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    rpost2019.05 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    rpost2019.06 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    regplan.2019.01.meanot.2018.01_amount = c(3794.4, 3794.4, 
    3794.4, 3794.4, 3794.4, 2514.54, 2514.54, 2514.54, 2514.54, 
    2514.54), regplan.2019.02.meanot.2018.02_amount = c(2529.6, 
    2529.6, 2529.6, 2529.6, 2529.6, 1436.88, 1436.88, 1436.88, 
    1436.88, 1436.88), regplan.2019.03.meanot.2018.03_amount = c(4637.6, 
    4637.6, 4637.6, 4637.6, 4637.6, 3592.2, 3592.2, 3592.2, 3592.2, 
    3592.2), regplan.2019.04.meanot.2018.04_amount = c(2529.6, 
    2529.6, 2529.6, 2529.6, 2529.6, 2873.76, 2873.76, 2873.76, 
    2873.76, 2873.76), regplan.2019.05.meanot.2018.05_amount = c(1054, 
    1054, 1054, 1054, 1054, 3412.58982, 3412.58982, 3412.58982, 
    3412.58982, 3412.58982), regplan.2019.06.meanot.2018.06_amount = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1077.66, 1077.66, 1077.66, 1077.66, 1077.66), 
    meanot.2018.03 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("5.000000", "5.500000"), class = "factor"), 
    meanot.2018.04 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("6.000000", "8.000000"), class = "factor"), 
    meanot.2018.05 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("5.000000", "6.333333"), class = "factor"), 
    reg.voz.2019.03.reg.otgruz.план.шт.2019.03 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.00", class = "factor"), 
    reg.voz.2019.04.reg.otgruz.план.шт.2019.04 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.00", class = "factor"), 
    NewTT2019.03 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "0.000000", class = "factor"), NewTT2019.04 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.000000", class = "factor"), 
    NewTT2019.03_amount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), NewTT2019.04_amount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cfo", "code", "customer_name", 
"sales_volume_name", "shop_group_name", "product_id", "shop_code", 
"rpost2019.01", "rpost2019.02", "rpost2019.03", "rpost2019.04", 
"rpost2019.05", "rpost2019.06", "regplan.2019.01.meanot.2018.01_amount", 
"regplan.2019.02.meanot.2018.02_amount", "regplan.2019.03.meanot.2018.03_amount", 
"regplan.2019.04.meanot.2018.04_amount", "regplan.2019.05.meanot.2018.05_amount", 
"regplan.2019.06.meanot.2018.06_amount", "meanot.2018.03", "meanot.2018.04", 
"meanot.2018.05", "reg.voz.2019.03.reg.otgruz.план.шт.2019.03", 
"reg.voz.2019.04.reg.otgruz.план.шт.2019.04", "NewTT2019.03", 
"NewTT2019.04", "NewTT2019.03_amount", "NewTT2019.04_amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

-and the second table

```
 anyta=structure(list(data = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2019-01-04 00:00:00.000", "2019-02-04 00:00:00.000", 
"2019-03-04 00:00:00.000", "2019-04-04 00:00:00.000", "2019-05-04 00:00:00.000"
), class = "factor"), cfo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "НСК", class = "factor"), customer_name = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "TC", class = "factor"), 
    sales_volume_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "от 50 до 100 кг", class = "factor"), 
    shop_group_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "loc", class = "factor"), shop_code = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "02293НСК", class = "factor"), 
    product_id = c(11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11628L, 11709L, 
    11709L, 11709L, 11709L, 11709L), code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("PlanНСК1", "PlanНСК2", 
    "PlanНСК3", "PlanНСК4", "PlanНСК5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("data", 
"cfo", "customer_name", "sales_volume_name", "shop_group_name", 
"shop_code", "product_id", "code"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

as we can see in the second table has **data** column , and the first table doesn't have data column, but it has int columns

rpost 2019-01, 2019-02....rpost2019-06

01...06 is number of  months

01-jan

02-feb

03-mar

04-apr

05-may

06-jun

in second table  data in ymd format, i must look only on number of months, here **04**,  it is april

so, how to do that if  in second table  in data column number of month=04

then  then all numeric variables(begin from rpost) from first table  should start from this month

I.E. output

```
 cfo     code customer_name sales_volume_name shop_group_name product_id shop_code rpost2019.04 rpost2019.05 rpost2019.06 regplan.2019.04.meanot.2018.04_amount
1  НСК PlanНСК1            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11628  02293НСК            2            1            2                               2529.60
2  НСК PlanНСК2            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11628  02293НСК            2            1            2                               2529.60
3  НСК PlanНСК3            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11628  02293НСК            2            1            2                               2529.60
4  НСК PlanНСК4            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11628  02293НСК            2            1            2                               2529.60
5  НСК PlanНСК5            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11628  02293НСК            2            1            2                               2529.60
6  НСК PlanНСК1            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11709  02293НСК            2            3            1                               2873.76
7  НСК PlanНСК2            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11709  02293НСК            2            3            1                               2873.76
8  НСК PlanНСК3            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11709  02293НСК            2            3            1                               2873.76
9  НСК PlanНСК4            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11709  02293НСК            2            3            1                               2873.76
10 НСК PlanНСК5            ТС   от 50 до 100 кг             loc      11709  02293НСК            2            3            1                               2873.76
   regplan.2019.05.meanot.2018.05_amount regplan.2019.06.meanot.2018.06_amount X.
1                                1054.00                                  0.00  …
2                                1054.00                                  0.00  …
3                                1054.00                                  0.00  …
4                                1054.00                                  0.00  …
5                                1054.00                                  0.00  …
6                                3412.59                               1077.66  …
7                                3412.59                               1077.66  …
8                                3412.59                               1077.66  …
9                                3412.59                               1077.66  …
10                               3412.59                               1077.66  …
```

So in output 01-03 months are absent.
if in table anyta, in **data** column , 05 is indicated(MAY)
so return columns where 05 month is featured.
In data column of second table can't be different month

But notice, that in table itogo names of column maybe different

```
regplan 2019-01*meanot 2018-01_amount
regplan 2019-02*meanot 2018-02_amount
regplan 2019-03*meanot 2018-03_amount
regplan 2019-04*meanot 2018-04_amount
regplan 2019-05*meanot 2018-05_amount
regplan 2019-06*meanot 2018-06_amount
meanot 2018-03
meanot 2018-04
meanot 2018-05
reg voz 2019-03/reg otgruz план шт 2019-03
reg voz 2019-04/reg otgruz план шт 2019-04
NewTT2019-03
NewTT2019-04
NewTT2019-03_amount
NewTT2019-04_amount
```

if we have two data in col.names like

```
 regplan 2019-01*meanot 2018-01_amount
```

so output from regplan 2019-0**4***meanot 2018-0**4**_amount

```
NewTT2019-03_amount
```

in this data column output from NewTT2019-**04**_amount

How to create such condition

Comment: `anyta` didn't copy/paste correctly

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand your explanation of the relationship between the tables. But, it looks like you've essentially got data contained in the column names. One approach would be to incorporate this into the table itself by reshaping the table (`melt` in `data.table` would be one approach)

Comment: @MichaelChiricom, yes , i fixed, please try run.

Comment: How can i use melt in this case? Can you show please